# Displaying color in NCurses window

Tags: ncurses

In the code below, why don't I see color text/background?

```c
    #include <ncurses.h>
    
    int main()
    {
            initscr();
    
            int lines = 20;
            int cols = 30;
            int y = 1;
            int x = 1;
    
            WINDOW* win = newwin(lines, cols, y, x);
    
            start_color();
            init_pair(1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_RED);
    
            attrset(COLOR_PAIR(1));
            mvwprintw(win, 2, 2, "Some words...\n\n");
            /* mvprintw(2, 2, "Some words...\n\n");// this works! (with refresh())*/
            attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    
            wrefresh(win);
    
            return 0;
    }
```

I'd like to know how to display color text/background inside ncurses window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more issues:

1. you don't correctly end ncurses
2. you set colours for default window (for window named `screen`), but you used print to own window.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    int lines = 20;
    int cols = 30;
    int y = 1;
    int x = 1;
    WINDOW* win;

    initscr();
    start_color();

    win = newwin(lines, cols, y, x);
    init_pair(1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_RED);

    wattron(win, COLOR_PAIR(1));
    mvwprintw(win, 2, 2, "Some words...\n\n");
    wattroff(win, COLOR_PAIR(1));
    wrefresh(win);

    /* wait on press any key */
    getchar();

    /* close ncurses */
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```